# python, kivy, geopy, buildozer

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer, geopy

I have successfully compiled a few android packages with buildozer (e.g 'openweather' works just fine with an API key).
My Kivy file works fine.
When I include geopy, buildozer successfully compiles the kivy file, but the app crashes when I ask for the Lat/Lon position.
I have an API key from Nominatim/MapQuest:
in the 'main.py file': user_agent='API_key' or 'app_name' or my email address

in the buildozer'spec file':
requirements: pytyhon3, kivy, geopy
android.permissions= INTERNET

My question, what am I doing wrong?
Regards
Sybe

Answer (score 0):

The permissions should be `android.permissions = INTERNET, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`, if you need access to the devices gps.

Try to rebuilding your app with those permissions included and post the logcat output if it still crashes

Comment: I did add the permission, but I don't think I need it because I just want the app to give Lat/Lon when I ask for the Lat/Lon of some town.

Comment: sorry i keep pressing return by mistake. I've run logcat and will study results. One thing, can i use the urllib3 library instead of Geopy?

Comment: Hi, I've tried urllib3 but get the same result. I've also run logcat, but cannot see anything. How do I post my logcat file for you to look at?

Comment: if you have your apk already on your phone run buildozer android logcat, start the app and then check the console output, if you have already uninstalled the app try buildozer android deploy run logcat to launch the app directly after the installation and get the logs.

Comment: thanks I'll try. I'll let you know when I've got the answer to post

Comment: Hi, I'm still at it. The log file looks fine and the app opens fine.  Have the app on my device and the phone in developers mode. App returns 'waiting for debugger to attach'. Any other idea?